# Densitiy of bivariate normal distribution

Tags: multivariable-calculus, covariance

> > Let $Y$ and $X$ be bivariat normal distributed with expectation vector $\mu=(\mu_Y,\mu_X)^T$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma=\begin{pmatrix}\sigma_Y^2 & p_{XY}\\p_{XY} & \sigma_X^2\end{pmatrix}$. Determine the density $f_{X,Y}$.

I know that the density in general form is given by
$$
f_{Y,X}(y,x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\lvert\Sigma\rvert^{-1/2}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{pmatrix}Y \\ X\end{pmatrix}-\mu\right)^T\Sigma^{-1}\left(\begin{pmatrix}Y \\ X\end{pmatrix}-\mu\right)\right).
$$

**Update**

I determined the densitiy as

$$
f_{(Y,X)}(y,x)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{\sigma_Y^2\sigma_X^2-p_{XY}^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2(\sigma_Y^2\sigma_X^2-p_{XY}^2)}(\sigma_X^2(y-\mu_Y)^2-2p_{XY}(x-\mu_X)(y-\mu_Y)+\sigma_Y^2(x-\mu_X)^2\right)
$$

Can anybody tell me if that is correct?

Comment: look at the inverse of a $2X2$ matrix.

Comment: By the way: What is meant with $p_{XY}$? Is that $\text{cov}(X,Y)$?

Comment: for example: $\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}^{-1}=\frac{1}{det(\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix})}\begin{bmatrix}d & -b\\-c & a\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Then here it is $\Sigma^{-1}=\frac{1}{\sigma_Y^2\sigma_X^2-p_{XY}^2}\begin{pmatrix}\sigma_X^2 & -p_{XY}\\-p_{XY} & \sigma_Y^2\end{pmatrix}$. But what is $p_{XY}$ standing for? And can I simplify the determinant?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know. I had to do a similar exercise last week, see here exercise 5 http://www.math.uzh.ch/index.php?file&key1=27972.  maybe this http://mpdc.mae.cornell.edu/Courses/MAE714/biv-normal.pdf can also help

Comment: $p_{XY}$ is the covariance. $\frac{p_{XY}}{\sigma_X \sigma_Y}$ is the correlation.

Comment: You mean $p_{XY}=cov(X,Y) $?