# Show that $E(Y\mid X=x)$ is a linear function in $x$

Tags: statistics, proof-verification, stochastic-integrals

> > Let $Y$ and $X$ be bivariate normal distributed with expectationvector $\mu=(\mu_Y,\mu_X)^T$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma=\begin{pmatrix}\sigma_Y^2 & p_{XY}\\p_{XY} & \sigma_X^2\end{pmatrix}$. Show that the conditional expectation $E(Y\mid X=x)$ is a linear function in $x$.

Hello!

To my knowledge it is
$$
E(Y\mid X=x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}y\cdot f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)\, dy.
$$
So first I tried to determine $f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)$ by
$$
f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)=\frac{f_{Y,X}(y,x)}{f_X(x)}.
$$

To my calculation this is
$$
f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)=\frac{\sigma_X}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{\sigma_Y^2\sigma_X^2-p_{XY}^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2(\sigma_Y^2\sigma_X^2-p_{XY}^2)}\cdot(\sigma_X^2(y-\mu_Y)^2-2p_{XY}(x-\mu_X)(y-\mu_Y)+\sigma_Y^2(x-\mu_X)^2)+\frac{1}{2}\frac{(x-\mu_X)^2}{\sigma_X^2}\right)
$$

Is that right?

In case it is: How can I know determine

$$
\int y\cdot f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)\, dy,
$$
i.e. how can I determine
$$
\frac{\sigma_X}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{\sigma_Y^2\sigma_X^2-p_{XY}^2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}y\cdot\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2(\sigma_Y^2\sigma_X^2-p_{XY}^2)}\cdot(\sigma_X^2(y-\mu_Y)^2-2p_{XY}(x-\mu_X)(y-\mu_Y)+\sigma_Y^2(x-\mu_X)^2)+\frac{1}{2}\frac{(x-\mu_X)^2}{\sigma_X^2}\right)\, dy?
$$

Edit:

If I set 
$$
c:=-\frac{\sigma_X^2}{2(\sigma_Y^2\sigma_X^2-p_{XY}^2)}, d:=\frac{2p_{XY}(x-\mu_X)}{2(\sigma_Y^2\sigma_X^2-p_{XY}^2)}, q:=\frac{\sigma_Y^2(x-\mu_X)^2}{2(\sigma_Y^2\sigma_X^2-p_{XY}^2)}
$$
and
$$
w:=\frac{(x-\mu_X)^2}{2\sigma_X^2}
$$
then I have to calculate the following:
$$
\frac{\sigma_X\exp(-q+w)}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{\sigma_Y^2\sigma_X^2-p_{XY}^2}}\int y\cdot\exp(c(y-\mu_Y)^2+d(y-\mu_Y))\, dy
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on working with densities, then note that the joint density of $(X,Y)$ is given by
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma_X\sigma_Y\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\exp\Big(-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}r(x,y)\Big),
$$
with
$$
r(x,y)=\frac{(x-\mu_X)^2}{\sigma_X^2}-2\rho\frac{(x-\mu_X)}{\sigma_X}\frac{(y-\mu_Y)}{\sigma_Y}+\frac{(y-\mu_Y)^2}{\sigma_Y^2}.
$$
Here $\rho$ is the correlation between $X$ and $Y$, i.e. $p_{XY}=\rho \sigma_X\sigma_Y$. Calculations (do these) now show that $r(x,y)$ can be written as
$$
r(x,y)=-\frac{1}{2\sigma_X^2}(x-\mu_X)^2-\frac{1}{2\sigma_Y^2(1-\rho^2)}\Big(y-\mu_Y-\frac{\rho\sigma_Y}{\sigma_X}(x-\mu_X)\Big)^2
$$
and hence $f_{X,Y}$ factors into the product of
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_X}\exp\Big(-\frac{1}{\sigma_X^2}(x-\mu_X)^2\Big)\tag{1}
$$
and
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_Y(1-\rho^2)}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma_Y^2(1-\rho^2)}\Big(y-\mu_Y-\frac{\rho\sigma_Y}{\sigma_X}(x-\mu_X)\Big)^2\right)\tag{2}
$$
showing that the conditional density of $Y$ given $X=x$ is given by $(2)$, i.e. $Y\mid X=x$ is normally distributed with mean $\mu_Y+\rho\frac{\sigma_Y}{\sigma_X}(x-\mu_X)$ and variance $\sigma_Y^2(1-\rho^2)$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/774538/densitiy-of-bivariate-normal-distribution This is MY joint density.

Comment: Sorry, I've used a different parameterization. Here $\rho=p_{XY}/(\sigma_X\sigma_Y)$. This answer still applies though.

Comment: Could you pls have a look on my edit here? I tried to simplify it. Is that right? If yes, how can I compute the integral in it?

Comment: You _don't_ want to compute any integrals. You want to identify the conditional density as a normal density and then you can easily identify the mean.

Comment: The tutor gave the hint to use the formula for conditional expectation...

Comment: That's a stupid hint then.

Comment: But is my joint density at least right?

Comment: Yes, it's the same as mine if you apply that $p_{XY}=\rho\sigma_X\sigma_Y$. This you can verify yourself.

Comment: Ok, and do I HAVE to  use $p_{XY}=p\sigma_X\sigma_Y$? The problem is, that I do not see how I can come from my joint density to a form that helps me.

Comment: Of course you don't have to. You can just modify my answer to your situation. If you plug in $\rho=p_{XY}/(\sigma_X\sigma_Y)$ into the rewritten expression for $r(x,y)$ above, then you know what you have to arrive at.

Comment: Ok. And is my result for $f_{Y|X}$ right, too?

Comment: I think your r is not right, I think it has to be (in your notation) $\sigma_X^2(y-\mu_Y)-2p\frac{(x-\mu_X)}{\sigma_X}\frac{y-\mu_y)}{\sigma_Y}+\sigma_Y^2(x-\mu_X)^2$.

Comment: And I do not understand why your proof shows that the conditional expectation is a linear function in x. Can you explain that?

Comment: My $r$ is correct. Note the factor $-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}$ that is multiplied to $r$ in the expression for the joint density. You know that $Y\mid X=x$ is normally distributed and you have its pdf. Can't you read the mean from that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14241/discussion-between-math12-and-stefan-hansen)

Comment: Minor point: I think it should be $\mu_Y+\cdots$, and not minus. In your density, $(y-\mu_Y-\frac{\rho\sigma_X}{\sigma_Y}(x-\mu_X))=(y-(\mu_Y+\frac{\rho\sigma_X}{\sigma_Y}(x-\mu_X)))$.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @hejseb.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to work directly on random variables: there exists some parameters $(a,b)$ and a standard normal random variable $Z$ independent of $X$ such that $Y-\mu_Y=a(X-\mu_X)+bZ$ (*can you show this?*), thus $E(Z\mid X)=E(Z)=0$ hence $E(Y\mid X)=\mu_Y+a(X-\mu_X)$. To compute $a$, note that $\mathrm{Cov}(Y,X)=a\cdot\mathrm{var}(X)+b\cdot\mathrm{Cov}(Z,X)$ and $\mathrm{Cov}(Z,X)=0$, hence $\rho_{XY}=a\cdot\sigma^2_X$.

Comment: I would prefer to calculate it directly.

Comment: And very wrong to prefer that, you are.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your answer... therefore I thought it might be okay to calculate it directly.

Comment: Pls see my edit

Comment: What do you fail to understand in my answer? Sorry but said answer is nearly empty...

Comment: I do not understand this role of $Z$...

Comment: Don't you have somewhere in your notes a result saying the form conditionings can have when they imply a gaussian family?

Comment: No, sorry, I do not know what you mean...

Comment: Working on gaussian conditionings with no lecture notes, no nothing? (This might explain why you insist on NOT using the correct approaches...) Sorry but how come?

Comment: We got this task although multivariate normal distribution is later in the script. Its not my fault.

Comment: Oh so you DO have notes, finally. And you were asked an exercise beginning with "Let Y and X be bivariate normal distributed" although you do not know what a bivariate normal distribution is, yet? Hmmm... Where do they do that?

Comment: Yes, this is my situation! Multivariate normal distributions will be treated later.. and THEN we get the parts of the script to that.. although NOW this task is asked.

Comment: "Where do they do that?"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate directly, try *massaging* your expression for 
$f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid X=x)$ into the form
$$f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid X=x) = \frac{\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{y-a}{b}\right)^2\right)}{b\sqrt{2\pi}}$$
where $a$ and $b$ are functions of $x$ and the other parameters but
do *not* depend on $y$. Then see if you can determine the expected
value *without* doing the integration that you propose to carry out.

Comment: What do you think of my edit? Is that the right way?

Comment: Can you pls help me to bring my $f_{Y|X}$ in this form? I do not know how to do so.