# Bringing a density in a normal distribution form

Tags: statistics, proof-verification, normal-distribution, expectation

Because I do not want to exaggerate this thread [Show that $E(Y\mid X=x)$ is a linear function in $x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/775643/show-that-eyx-x-is-a-linear-function-in-x)
I continue my special problem here.

In order to make the setting clear I'll give some information. $Y$ and $X$ are bivariate normal distributed with expectation vector $\mu=(\mu_Y,\mu_X)^T$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma=\begin{pmatrix}\sigma_Y^2 & p_{XY}\\p_{XY} & \sigma_X^2\end{pmatrix}$ and the task is to show that the conditional expectation $E(Y\mid X=x)$ is a linear function in $x$. My calculation came to the fact, that the conditional density is given by
$$
f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)=\frac{\sigma_X}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{\sigma_Y^2\sigma_X^2-p_{XY}^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2(\sigma_Y^2\sigma_X^2-p_{XY}^2)}\cdot(\sigma_X^2(y-\mu_Y)^2-2p_{XY}(x-\mu_X)(y-\mu_Y)+\sigma_Y^2(x-\mu_X)^2)+\frac{1}{2}\frac{(x-\mu_X)^2}{\sigma_X^2}\right).
$$

**Update**

Now I made a lot of calculations and brought my $f_{Y|X}$ into the form
$$
f_{Y|X}(y|x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\frac{\sqrt{\lvert\Sigma}}{\sigma_X}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\frac{\lvert\Sigma}{\sigma_X^2}}\cdot\left(y-\left(\frac{p_{XY}\mu_X}{\sigma_X^2}-\frac{p_{XY}x}{\sigma_X^2}-\mu_Y\right)\right)^2+r(x)\right),
$$
whereat $r$ is a function only depending on $x$.

This is - apart from the summand $r(x)$ - the density of the normal distribution with expectation $\lambda(x):=\frac{p_{XY}\mu_X}{\sigma_X^2}-\frac{p_{XY}x}{\sigma_X^2}-\mu_Y$ and variance $\theta^2:=\frac{\lvert\Sigma\rvert}{\sigma_X^2}$.

Now do I see it right, that it has to be $r(x)=0$, because of the condition

$$
\int f_{Y|X}(y|x)\, dy=1,
$$
i.e.
$$
\int f_{Y|X}(y|x)\, dy\\
=\exp(r(x))\cdot\overbrace{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\frac{\sqrt{\lvert\Sigma}}{\sigma_X}}\int\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\frac{\lvert\Sigma}{\sigma_X^2}}\cdot\left(y-\left(\frac{p_{XY}\mu_X}{\sigma_X^2}-\frac{p_{XY}x}{\sigma_X^2}-\mu_Y\right)\right)^2\right)\, dy}^{=1}\\
=1\\
\Leftrightarrow \exp(r(x))=1\\
\Leftrightarrow r(x)=0?
$$

If yes, it is shown that $Y|X=x\sim\mathcal{N}(\lambda(x),\theta^2)$ and so
$$
E(Y|X=x)=\lambda(x)
$$
and $\lambda$ is a linear function in $x$.

Can anybody tell me if my proof is correct, please?

With regards

math12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: simplify your problem by assuming $\mu_X = \mu_Y = 0$ and $\sigma_X = \sigma_Y = 1$. It should not be hard to argue that if the original relationship is linear, then this new relationship will also be linear.

EDIT: because $Z = (X - \mu_X)/\sigma_X$ is a *linear* relation that makes a variable standard Normal.

Once you've done that: isolate terms $A,B$ in  $-Ay^2 + By$ in the exponent, then you will get $a= B/(2A)$.

Note that the "free term" $C$ in the expression

$$exp(-Ay^2 + By + C) $$ does not matter. I wouldn't even bother checking for it. Why? Because by definition, this expression is a conditional density. Therefore, it must integrate to 1. Therefore, $(-Ay^2 + By + C) $ must already be a complete square.

EDITED: the new calculation seems ok.

However, I still don't understand why you keep dragging $\mu, \sigma$ around. Mathematics is about simplifying things!

Comment: If I set it I get $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{1-p_{XY}^2}}\exp(-\frac{1}{2(1-p_{XY}^2)}(y^2-2p_{XY}xy+x^2+\frac{x^2}{2})$. And now?

Comment: now $A = 1$ and $B = 2\rho_{XY}x$. You just complete the square in the expression $(y^2 - 2\rho xy)$

Comment: Hm, I am sorry, but I do not know what you mean!

Comment: Do you mean: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{1-p_{XY}^2}}\exp(-\frac{1}{2(1-p_{XY}^2)}\cdot ((y-p_{XY} x)^2-p_{XY}^2x^2+x^2+\frac{x^2}{2})$?

Comment: Yes. for example, $y^2 - 6y + C_1 = (y-3)^2 + C_2$ constants $C_{1,2}$ don't really matter

Comment: Ok! Now I have that $f_{Y|X}(y|x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{1-p_{XY}^2}}\exp(-\frac{1}{2}\frac{(y-p_{XY}x)^2}{(1-p_{XY}^2)}+C)$. Whats the next step?

Comment: Ehm... why must $C$ be 0?

Comment: Sorry $C$ is not quite $0$. But see my edited answer above.

Comment: Maybe you can say me if my solution resp. proof that I added (see Update) is correct? Thanks!

Comment: I did not understand why I can assume wlog that $\sigma_X^2=1=\sigma_Y^2$ and $\mu_X=\mu_Y=0$. Therefore I did it without this simplyfication.