# conditional expectation of two independent normal random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Show that conditional expectation of two independent normal random variable $(X,Y) \approx N(m=(m_1,m_2), \Sigma)$ is equal:

$$E[X|Y] = m_1 + \rho \frac{\sigma_X}{\sigma_Y}(Y-m_2)$$

Is there any way to prove it using definition of conditional expectation $E[X|Y] = \frac{1}{P(Y)} \int_Y XdP$ ?

Of course, I can prove it using probability density function $f_{X|Y} = \frac{f(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$ but this way is very long.

I will grateful for tips.

Comment: For a way that avoids densities, see [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/775658/25632).

Comment: "independent" $\implies\rho=0$. Please make up your mind.

Comment: Just for the record, the formula $E[X|Y] = \frac{1}{P(Y)} \int_Y XdP$ is absurd.